# How to check if a dynamic lib correctly implements an interface

Tags: c++, c++11, dll, shared-libraries

I'm trying to load a class from a dynamic librairy.
This class need to inherit from an interface named `IDisplayModule` :

```
class IDisplayModule {
public:
    virtual ~IDisplayModule() = default;
    virtual const std::string &getName() const = 0;
};
```

I've created a `DLLoader` class which is used to load a dynamic lib :

```
template <typename T>
class DLLoader {
private:
    std::string _libraryPath;
    void *_handle;

public:
    DLLoader<T>(const std::string &libraryPath) try : _libraryPath(libraryPath), _handle(NULL) {
        _handle = dlopen(_libraryPath.c_str(), RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
        if (!_handle)
            throw DLLoaderException("On dlopen of " + _libraryPath, "DLLoader");
    } catch (DLLoaderException &e) {
        throw e;
    }; 

    T *getInstance(const std::string &entryPoint) const {
        T *(*fptr)(void);
        T *obj = NULL;

        void *ret = dlsym(_handle, entryPoint.c_str());
        if (!ret)
            throw DLLoaderException("On dlsym of " + _libraryPath + dlerror() + "DLLoader");
        fptr = reinterpret_cast<T *(*)(void)>(ret);
        obj = dynamic_cast<T *>(fptr());
        if (!obj)
            throw DLLoaderException("On cast of " + _libraryPath + dlerror() + "DLLoader");
        return (obj);
    };

    ~DLLoader<T>() { 
        dlclose(_handle); 
    };     
};
```

From now, my `DLLoader` is functional.
My problem is if someone :

- creates an `IDisplayModule`, but without the `getName` method
- creates a dynamic library with a class named `WrongClass` which inherits from **his** `IDisplayModule`

His `WrongClass` doesn't implement the `getName` method, and after my `DLLoader` has loaded his library, my program crashes when I call the `getName` method.

**I understand why it crashes**, but I want to avoid it. How can I handle this error ?

Here's my test function :

```
int main(void)
{
    try {
        DLLoader<IDisplayModule> lib = DLLoader<IDisplayModule>("./wrongLib.so");
        IDisplayModule *libInstance = lib.getInstance("entryPoint");
        std::cout << libInstance->getName() << std::endl;
    } catch (DLLoaderException &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and here's an example of a `WrongClass` on `wrongLib.so` :

```
class WrongClass : public IDisplayModule {
private:
    std::string _name;
public:
    lib1();
   ~lib1();
};

extern "C" {
    IDisplayModule *entryPoint()
        return (new WrongClass());
}
```

Comment: One more thing you need to take into account: `std::string`'s implementation varies wildly between compilers and even versions of compilers. You need to be very careful when passing around data structures that you do not completely control.

Comment: How does this even compile? `getName` is a pure virtual function. `WrongClass` has to implement it, otherwise you cannot create an instance of that type.

Comment: It compile because the guy who is created WrongClass took my IDisplayModule, but he delete the getName method. Like that, he can compile his library, with his WrongClass class and his IDisplayModule

Comment: Well in that case your `IDisplayModule` isn't `WrongClass`'s `IDisplayModule`. They're two distinct types and you violate the strict aliasing rule by trying to reinterpret one to another.

Comment: Yes, that's it. This guy isn't implementing the good `IDisplayModule`, but how can my program detects that it isn't a good implementation ?

Comment: Can you modify the implementation of `entyPoint`?

Comment: Forget my last comment. Not even `typeid` can distinguish between the normal and broken type. I think you're out of luck, even with non-standard c++.

Comment: No problem, you tried, I'll wait for an answer

Comment: I don't think you'll get one. At least not a positive one. You basically have to deal with an ABI break here. There is no solution except recompile the dll.

Comment: C++ doesn't really work well with dynamic loading. The only safe method is importing/exporting pure `extern "C"` functions.